Какая функция нужна, чтобы черепашка сделала круг?
music.forward(100)
music.left(10)
music.forward(200)
music.right(10)
for loop in range(1, 8):
    music.left(45)
    music.forward(145)
music.left(35)
music.forward(200)
music.left(10)
music.forward(100)

И у меня конечно выходит так. (Я так и планировал.) Но хочется больше круг:


https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/turtle-circle-method-in-python/

Попробуй t.circle(100), в скобках радиус круга.

Спасибо! попробовал всё работает.

import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()

N = 100 # Количество сторон, чем больше, тем многоугольник круглее
for _ in range(N):
    t.forward(10)
    t.left(360 / N)


Из странных методов - можно использовать параметрическое уравнение окружности

x = R * cos(t), y = R * sin(t), 0 <= t < 2π

import turtle
from math import *

def circle(r):
  turtle.sety(r)
  turtle.clear()
  T = 0
  while T < 2 * pi:
    x = r * sin(T)
    y = r * cos(T)
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    T += 0.01

circle(100)


mrgervant а зачем из математики умножение доставать? Или в твоем компиляторе, ( Это программа где ты писал код.) Python не понимает сначала математики, и нужно всё доставать?

Функции синуса, косинуса и значение
pi вынесены в отдельный модуль math. Звёздочка * в данном случае это
не умножение, а оператор распаковки - импортировать всë из модуля. Можно и конкретно прописать было (что надёжнее) - но просто хотелось написать покороче

Понял. Хотя я всё равно не понимаю, почему не сделали так чтобы все эти ариффмитические уровнения сразу можно написать, а не доставать?
